# Start activity with ExpandableListView from another activity

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Hello i would like to start an activity and also a list view from another activity but i can't understand how to do it.

This is the Expandable adapter

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

// constructor
public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern)
{
    this.parentItems = parents;
    this.childtems = childern;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) 
{
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.activity = activity;
}

// method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
//  Implement this method as per your requirement
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

    TextView textView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
    }

     // get the textView reference and set the value
    textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
    textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

    // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
   /* convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); */
    return convertView;
}

// method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
// Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
    }

    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() 
{
    return parentItems.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) 
{
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
{
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() 
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return false;
}

}
```

This is my first activity

```
public class ConversationsListActivity extends   ConversationsEssentialActivity{

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.conversations_list);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
    FontHelper.applyFont(this, findViewById(R.id.phrasebookList), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); /**  **/

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversationsList);
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.conversations_list_array);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.conversations_list_items, drawerListViewItems));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){

                case 0:{

                    Intent Info = new Intent(ConversationsListActivity.this, ConversationsEssentialActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(Info, position);

                    setGroupParentsEssential();
                    setChildDataEssential();

                }
                break;


            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is my second activity

```
public class ConversationsEssentialActivity extends   Activity{

  // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
  ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
  ExpandableListView list;
  MyExpandableAdapter adapter2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.show();
  list = new ExpandableListView(this);

  list.setDividerHeight(2);
  list.setGroupIndicator(null);
  list.setClickable(true);

  adapter2 = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

  adapter2.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);

  // Set the Adapter to expandableList
  list.setAdapter(adapter2);

  setContentView(list);

}

   // method to add parent Items
  public void setGroupParentsEssential() 
  {

  parentItems.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_1));
  parentItems.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_2));
  parentItems.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_3));
  parentItems.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_4));
  parentItems.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_5));


  }

  // method to set child data of each parent
  public void setChildDataEssential() 
  {


  ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_1t));
  childItems.add(child);


  child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_2t));
  childItems.add(child);


  child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_3t));
  childItems.add(child);


  child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_4t));
  childItems.add(child);


  child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add(getResources().getString(R.string.essential_5t));
  childItems.add(child);


  }

}
```

the child_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/childView"  >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#75a800"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the parent_view.xml

```
<CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textViewGroupName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

The first activity, on click, should start the second activity and also launch setGroupParentsEssential();  and setChildDataEssential(); which are declared in the second activity. But on click, it just open the second activity with blank screen.

Does someone provide me an example on how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Any help? i can't understand how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a layout for your activity, try referencing this layout using:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourxmlfile);
   ...
}
```

The layout itself should define the listview

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i don't have a layout for the expandable list view. i have 2 layout, one for parent and one for child